# Could anyone confirm my poor translation of these few sentences?

Tags: translation

For my first question I would like some help on the following message I received(the sentences are relatively simple since my Japanese skills are quite low). But before starting I would like to say that this is the answer I got from a Japanese school to who I was asking a way of contacting an old friend of mine.

> Dear Ephismen,
>
> こんにちは。おげんきですか？  メールありがとうござます。  こちらはみんなげんきです。 
>   Personさんのれんらくさきは、こじんじょうほうなので  おしえられませんが、Ephismenさんのれんらくさきをメールで 
>   おくることはできます。  Personさんにメールしましょうか？

Here is the interpretation I made of it:

> Hello. Are you fine? Thank you for your e-mail. Here everyone is ok. Mr. Person does not study with us anymore, moreover the information you are asking are confidential, however we could transmit your informations to him. Would you like us to send this mail to him?

As I said before this is an interpretation and not a translation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cordially, Ephismen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Hello. Are you fine? Thank you for your e-mail. Here everyone is ok. Since Person's contact information is private information, we cannot tell you that, but we can e-mail Ephismen's contact information (to Person). Shall we e-mail to Person?

You got the message correctly overall (except that it does not explicitly say Person does not study there anymore, but probably that is the case).

Comment: Agreed, about the Person not studying there anymore part.  It could just be that the information is generally protected as "personal information" and that they just want to verify that Person wants to have his contact information given to someone.